# DateFormatter displaying Date Wrongly in iPhone device

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

Hi I need to convert dateString to Date.
 Example: dateString = **15 Nov 2017**

But after conversion Date coming as **2017-11-14 18:30:00 +0000**

here is my code

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US_POSIX") as Locale!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: "15 Nov 2017")
```

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine. The printed date is correct based on your timezone.

Comment: But how can i solve this issue

Comment: There is no issue to solve.

Comment: just use date formatter string from date

Comment: and use Locale instead of NSLocale. `Locale(identifier:"en_US_POSIX")`